MVC issue,request not processing
index.js (main)
const express = require("express");
const app =express();

const {connectMongoose} = require("./connection.js");
connectMongoose("mongodb://localhost:27017/").then(console.log("MongoDbConnected Successfully"));

const { logReqRes } = require("./middlewares/index");
// logReqRes();

const router = require("./routes/user.js");

const PORT = 8000;

//middlwares
app.use(express.urlencoded({extends : false}));
app.use(logReqRes('./log.txt'));

//routes
app.use("/user",router);

app.listen(PORT,()=>{console.log("server started",PORT)});

connection.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
async function connectMongoose(url){
    console.log("connection starts");
    return mongoose.connect((url));
    
}

module.exports = {connectMongoose};

user.js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const {handleGetAllUsers,handleGetUserById,handleUpdateUserByID,handledeleteUserById} = require("../controllers/user");
console.log("router.req=>",router.req);

router.route("/").get(()=>handleGetAllUsers);

router.route("/:id").delete(()=>handledeleteUserById).patch(()=>handleUpdateUserByID).get(()=>handleGetUserById);

module.exports = router;

controllers.js
const { model } = require("mongoose");
const user_mongoose = require("../models/user")
 
async function handleGetAllUsers(req,res){
    const user = await user_mongoose.find({});
    res.json(user); 
}

async function handleGetUserById(req,res){
    console.log("getalluser starts");
    var user = await user_mongoose.findById(req.params.id);
    return res.json(user);
}

async function handleUpdateUserByID(req,res){
    var user = await user_mongoose.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{first_name:"Yashit Jain"}) ;
    res.send(await user_mongoose.findById(req.params.id));
}

async function handledeleteUserById(req,res){
    const userId = req.params.id; // take id to number
    const user = await user_mongoose.findByIdAndDelete(userId);
    res.send(user);
}
model.exports={
    handleGetAllUsers,
    handleGetUserById,
    handleUpdateUserByID,
    handledeleteUserById,
}

models.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

//schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    first_name : {
        type:String,
        require : true
    },
    last_name : {
        type:String,
    },
    email : {
        type : String,
        require : true,
        unique : true
    },
    gender : {
        type : String,
        require : true
    },
    title : {
        type : String,
    }
},{timestamps:true})
//model

const user_mongoose = mongoose.model("user",userSchema);

module.exports = user_mongoose;

On generating request it does not process the request,
even no error comes while generating request.
I segregate the conde into MVC i.e media-view-controller format, now it does not work.
Earlier when it was in a single JavaScript file it was working quite well.

Replace router.route("/").get(()=>handleGetAllUsers); with router.route("/").get(handleGetAllUsers);
()=>handleGetAllUsers
// "unpacked" =>
function (){
return handleGetAllUsers
}

When receiving a request, you are just returning the function to call. You should be calling it either by adding () to its name, or by directly passing it as the value so the dispatcher can call it.
EIDT:
Also, doing like you do, you are not even taking the parameters req,res from the call: get(()=>handleGetAllUsers) the parens are empty here, discarding the needed req,res parameters.
